# Add a file in clearcase which has space in name

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rad

In a project I have a file "My ProjectUtil.dll" . How can I add this file in clearcase. It seems to me that clearcase does not accept files which contains space in name. I tried to add it through RAD and command line but it is saying remove space from name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add it through the command-line ([`cleartool mkelem`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkelem.htm)):

```
cd /path/tp/parent/folder
cleartool co -c "add My ProjectUtil.dll" .
cleartool mkelem -nc "My ProjectUtil.dll"
cleartool ci -nc "My ProjectUtil.dll"
cleartool ci -nc .
```

(Or through a GUI, ClearCase Explorer, opened in addition of your RAD)

Note: Make sure your "My ProjectUtil.dll" hasn't actually a space at the beginning or or the end of its name (as in "My ProjectUtil.dll "). That wouldn't be well supported by a GUI.

Comment: Through clearcase explorer in RAD I tried to add but it says you need to remove the space by underscore.

Comment: @user1951754 And through a ClearCase Explorer *outside* RAD? (launched by your ClearCase installation, unless you have a CCRC or ClearTeam)

Comment: I don't have that tools installed. I will try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @user1951754 if RAD can do ClearCase operation, it must be linked to a ClearCase. It would be interesting to know what exact ClearCase version or type of have (full client or CCRC or, with 8.0, ClearTeam)

Comment: I tried command cleartool mkelem -nc "My ProjectUtil.dll" but it kept waiting forever. So canceled the operation. And regarding any other clearcase client we are not allowed to install it.Any ways thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1951754 So you do have a full ClearCase installed already. What do `cleartool -ver` returns? And do you see any error message in the `views` section of the ClearCase logs (`Start -> Programs -> Rational Software -> Rational ClearCase -> Administration -> Log Browser`)?